# Linux kernel: Insert a new variable in the PCB and feed data from a user application to kernel

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I am a newbies of linux kernel development. And now I am trying to compiler my own kernel.

My problem is that I want to insert a new variable into struct sched_entity, like that

```
struct sched_entity {

struct load_weight      load;
struct rb_node          run_node;
struct list_head        group_node;
unsigned int            on_rq;

u64                     exec_start;
u64                     sum_exec_runtime;
u64                     vruntime;
u64                     prev_sum_exec_runtime;
u64                     cache_miss_rate;   // the new variable I insert

u64                     nr_migrations;
.....
.....
}
```

for the new comming process I want to set the new variable as 1. Then after the process executed, I calculate the cache miss rate and I feed the data into the variable(update the variable), then use the data to modify some other parameter(e.g vruntime and slice) in the kernel.

But I do not how to initialize the new variable for the new comming process(I know that the child process would copy PCB from its parent process, but at the very beginning, the init process can not copy and has to initialize its PCB. I want to know how init process initialize its PCB so that I can modify it).

Besides, I also have trouble in finding out how to feed data into the new variable from a user level application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that `sched_entity` structure is initialized in [__sched_fork](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2077) function, defined in `kernel/sched/core.c`. `I also have trouble in finding out how to feed data into the new variable from a user level application.` - use any *user space - kernel space* interaction mechanism: additional system call, device files, and so on. Just google for that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the variable/data into a profs/sysfs file and let user space get/set the data from/to it, and kernel respond to those read/write operations